# How to compose emoji unicode dynamically from "1f628" to "\u{1f628}" with javascript

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, emoji

I'm trying to convert a unified string of emoji.

Getting error when trying to do this:

```
var code = '1f628'
`\u{${code}}`
```

> SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`String.fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) will get you the character from its numeric code point, and [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) will get you the number from a hex string:

```
var code = '1f628';
String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(code, 16)); //
```

Comment: i have tried ur code but its not working with below code >  \uD83D\uDE0A